# "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program." exception thrown when trying to run PowerShell script from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am attempting to execute a PowerShell script from a C# Windows forms application.

Code I am using is as follows,

```
private void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
    runspace.Open();

    RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    Command myCommand = new Command("D:\\MyScript.ps1");
    CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("hello");
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(insurerParam);
    pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

    pipeline.Invoke();
}
```

Whenever I execute this code it is throwing exception Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

Any help on where I am going wrong would be hugely appreciated as I am currently completely lost as I was so sure this would work (obviously not!).

TIA

Comment: The `Pipeline` class is PowerShell 2.0 legacy - use the [`PowerShell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx) class and the `AddScript()` method

Comment: Still getting same error here.            PowerShell psScript = PowerShell.Create();
            psScript.AddScript(@"MY SCRIPT HERE");
            psScript.AddArgument(VAR HERE);
            psScript.Invoke();